# String "Sunday" was not recognized as a valid Boolean

Tags: c#, boolean

I'm quite a beginner when it comes to programming so my problem might seem quite easy for most of people here. I'm trying to make an easy program where you write down a day of the week and it should show an information depending on an answer. I chose Sunday as a correct answer. I tried it with bool, with string but I had a problem with it not converting the answer so I don't really know what to do next.
Here's the code.

```
        Boolean day;
        Boolean Sunday = true;
        Boolean Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday = false;

    

        Console.Write("What's the day of the week today? Write your answer here: ");
        day = Boolean.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (Sunday == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your answer is correct!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorret. Please try again.");
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: C# cannot link the typed-in string to the name of some variable

Answer (score 0):

The user input you are expecting is a `string` of day of week, but your data type is `Boolean` which is either `true` or `false`.

So when converting from "Sunday" which will be user input for example, the code tries to convert to either true or false and throws exception.

You should write your program this way:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var currentDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday;
    // currentDayOfWeek = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek; // or if you want dynamically set todays day of week
    string userInputDayOfWeek;

    Console.Write("What's the day of the week today? Write your answer here: ");
    userInputDayOfWeek = Console.ReadLine();

    if ((Enum.TryParse(typeof(DayOfWeek), userInputDayOfWeek, ignoreCase: true, out object userInputParsed))
        && (DayOfWeek)userInputParsed == currentDayOfWeek)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is correct!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect. Please try again.");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Here we make use of enum `DayOfWeek` from the `System` namespace and we parse the user input with ignore case flag.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand reflections are out of the scope of your school project, so you can create a string array

```
    
    string trueDay = "Sunday";
    // or maybe better
      string trueDay=DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString();
    
    string[] falseDays = new string[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};


    Console.Write("What's the day of the week today? Write your answer here: ");
    var day = Console.ReadLine();

    if (day.ToLower() == trueDay.ToLower())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is correct!");
    }
    else if ( falseDays.Any( d =>d.ToLower()==day.ToLower() ))
    {
                
        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorret. Please try again.");
        
    } else
        Console.WriteLine("Please type a correct day name!");


    Console.ReadKey();
```

if Linq is not allowed too, try this

```
    var found=false;
    foreach (var item in falseDays)
    {
        if (item.ToLower() == day.ToLower())
        {  
            found=true;
            Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorret. Please try again.");
            break;
        }
    }
     if(!found) Console.WriteLine("Please type a correct day name!");
```